# NavigationUI set custom navigation icon

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-jetpack-navigation

With the Jetpack Navigation Library, the usual solutions to change hamburger menu icon in toolbar don't work, including:

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.my_drawer)
```

or

```
getSupportActionbar().setIcon(R.drawable.my_drawer)
```

> ^ both these methods do NOT work

Looks like NavigationUI library sets the hamburger & back icons in toolbar by its own & the icons are hardcoded in the library.

Is there a way to customize the navigation icon in toolbar when using Jetpack Navigation library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Navigation library does not provide any direct way to customize the hamburger or back icons, though there is a workaround.

Add an `addOnDestinationChangedListener()` to your navController. This is invoked **after** destination is changed & the lib has changed the icon in toolbar. Now in this callback e can change the toolbar's icon, like so:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController navController, @NonNull NavDestination navDestination, @Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                switch (navDestination.getId()) {
                    case R.id.homeFragment:
                        bottomNavigation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_hamburger); // <- this
                        break;
                    default:
                        bottomNavigation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

It helped me

```
class CustomToolbar @JvmOverloads constructor(
context: Context,
attrs: AttributeSet? = null) : Toolbar(context, attrs) {

override fun setNavigationIcon(icon: Drawable?) {
    if (icon == null) {
        super.setNavigationIcon(null)
    } else {
        val arrowDrawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_back)
        super.setNavigationIcon(arrowDrawable)
    }
}

override fun setNavigationIcon(resId: Int) {
    super.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_back)
}}
```